# Simplify two conditional probabilities

Tags: probability

Given $P(C) = P(A|B)$, is it possible to get $P(D|C)$ in terms of $A$, $B$, and $D$ only?

It seems like this should be some simple algebra, but I've been going around in circles trying to show it.

Comment: ...Bayes' Theorem?

Comment: I would think so, but that's where I can't seem to make the algebra work.

Comment: I'd summarize my issue as not realizing that you cannot assume there's any relationship at all between two events just because they have the same probability! Seems terribly obvious now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible.

Suppose you are tossing a fair die.

Let $A$ be the event "the toss is even".

Let $B$ be the event "the toss is $≤3$".

Let $C_1$ be the event "the toss is $≤2$"  So, indeed, $P(C_1)=\frac 13=P(A|B)$.

Let $C_2$ be the event "the toss is either $2$ or $4$".  Then again we have $P(C_2)=\frac 13=P(A|B)$ .

Let $D$ be the event "the toss is $1$".  Then $P(D|C_1)=\frac 12$ but $P(D|C_2)=0$ so $P(D|C)$ can't be determined from $A,B,D$ alone.

Comment: Both answers are great but I'll pick this one cause it laid out the counterexample so clearly.

Answer (score 1):

If you could write $P(D|C)$ in terms of $A$, $B$, and $D$ only, then given two events $C,C'$ such that $P(C) = P(C') = P(A|B)$ the probabilities $P(D|C)$ and $P(D|C')$ should be the same.

This is absurd. Take any $C$ and $C'$ that are disjoint and satisfy $P(C) = P(C') = P(A|B)\ne 0$. For example, consider flipping two fair coins, and let
$$ A = C = \{\text{coin 1 is heads}\}$$
$$ B = \{\text{coin 2 is heads}\} $$
$$ C' = \{\text{coin 1 is tails}\} $$
In this case, we have $P(C) = P(C') = P(A|B) = \frac{1}{2}$, and $P(C\cap C') = 0$.

If we let $D=C$, then $P(D|C) = 1$ and $P(D|C') = 0$. Thus, $P(D|C)$ can't be written in terms of $A$, $B$, and $D$ alone.